# MythTV backend configuration. Can't add myself as root user

Tags: permissions, mythbuntu, mythtv

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04. I received the following messages:

Message 1:

```
You must be a member of the "mythtv" group before starting any mythtv applications.  
Would you like to automatically be added to the group?  
(Note: sudo access required)
```

Message 2:

```
[Please enter your current login password to be added to the mythtv group]
```

When I enter my login password there is a pause, and the I get the message:

```
[Incorrect password.....Try again]
```

After 3 tries I get the message:

```
[Failed to run adduser 'david' 'mythtv' as user root. Wrong password]
```

Comment: The 'Failed to run ... as user root' is suspicious - I wonder if mythtv is using gksu under the hood and it's set to su mode instead of sudo mode? Have you tried running gksu-properties in a terminal and making sure the authentication mode is set to sudo?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The workaround is to do this manually - using the command:

```
sudo usermod -a G mythtv <userid>
```

(`<userid>` being your particular user login)

Use the following command to confirm the change:

```
id <userid>
```

You will need to restart/reboot to then successfully run mythtv

Comment: Many thanks for this information. However,there is a typo. Code should read:
sudo usermod -a -G mythtv <userid>
As a further gotcha, MythTv proceeds to ask for permission to stop the backend, then displays a dialogue box stating: "Please enter your current login password to stop mythtv-backend." The only way I have been able to proceed is by leaving the password field blank. My login password is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed mythtv and had the same issue.

[Steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) had the solution in a  comment. Run `gksu-properties`  and change the mode from `su` to `sudo`. This worked for me to fix the issue where it would not accept my password to stop/start the backend.